# How can I convert my Enjin coin to Ethereum

Tags: myetherwallet

My question is about how can I convert my Enjin coin to Ethereum in my MyEtherwallet? Thanks!

Genevieve

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange!

You need an exchange to sell your tokens for Ether. I think your [Enjin coin](https://enjincoin.io/) is the standard Ethereum token with the symbol `ENJ`. Thus you can use e.g. the fully decentralized exchange [EtherDelta](https://etherdelta.com/#ENJ-ETH) (hence it doesnt require any registration / KYC or any other account management!). You can for example install [MetaMask](https://metamask.io/) Chrome extension and send your ENJ from MyEtherWallet over to your Metamask account. Now you can deposit your ENJ with the EtherDelta smart contract and you can sell them for Ether (`ETH`) on EtherDelta if you think the price is right.

Please beware that EtherDelta is not always very liquid and hence you might get a bad price. Also note that MetaMask is running in your browser and currently I would not handle large amounts of money in there.

Answer (score 1):

You cant convert ENJIN coin (or any coin yet) just from within your MEW wallet. (maybe one day?) but you CAN put it into another wallet that supports swaps (by services called ShapeShift and Changelly) and exchanges within it.

you can do a google search for "built-in exchanges Shapeshift and Changelly."
**A**:
Id suggest getting CoinOmi on  your **android or iPhone** as that supports ENJIN coin and has both ShapeShift and Changelly built in.

check out EXODUS Wallet https://www.exodus.io/
its for **desktop** and it will support ENJIN sometime as well.

REMEMBER: you need a small amount of ETH to pay for GAS in your wallet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://ethersweep.com service - this should be the fastest and the most convenient way to scan your wallet and convert to Ethereum

Ethersweep can convert all majr ERC20 coins to ETH including Enjin coins